# does this inequality hold?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

this turned out to be wrong, see the comment of fedja below for the counter example.

$\sum_{m>0,n>0,k>0,m+n>k}\frac{1}{(m+n-k)^{1/2}\dot (m+n)^{1/2}}a_m a_n b_k$$\le$ C$\\|A\|_{l^2}^2$*$\|B\|_{l^2}$.

where A is the sery $\{a_m\},m=1,2,3...$, B is the sery $b_k, k=1,2,3...$.
C is a constant which is independent of A and B.
$\| \|_{l^2}$ denotes the $l^2$ Hilbert norm of the sequence.

Comment: Isn't this some kind of Cauchy-Schwartz argument?

Comment: sorry, can you be more specific? because I don't quite see that, what I'm thinking now is some extension of Hilbert's double series theorem.

Comment: This question could use a more specific title, and some motivation.

Comment: @jc I just meet this problem in summing up the dyadic decomposition in PDEs and need this inequality in one step, so I also don't have good motivation.

Comment: Anyway, there is no chance: if both sequences are $N^{-1/2}$ up to $N$, we have about $N^3$ terms each of which is at least $N^{-5/2}$, so the sum is $\ge N^{1/2}$.

Comment: @fedja: I tried the case for taking A and B to be harmonic series, it turned out that the above inequality holds.

Comment: Harmonic sequence is much better than just $\ell^2$. It is $\ell^{1+\epsilon}$. And it is rather meaningless to say that it holds for one pair of sequences, when you have a free constant $C$. 

Comment: Just to be more clear: fedja is essentially doing a scaling argument by taking $a_k$ and $b_k$ to be the scaled characteristic function. The RHS is held fixed, but the LHS is shown to be not scaling invariant. 

Comment: @Willie Wong: fedja is right, and thanks a lot for your comment, I don't know how to close this question.